# How do I get the quantity from every item in cart and pass to an activity?

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

i have a cartactivity and cartadapter, in cartadapter i add increment and decrement for each stuff, and i sum it in total price and total weight and send it to activity ( it worked by passing textview activity from cartactivity to adapteractivity ) and now i want to get seperated quantity for each item to send to database with format Example if item is ( Wallet, Bag, Shoes ) then quanitity that will send to database like this ( 2, 3, 3) 2 represent for wallet and (,) for seperating item quantity, 3 represent bag, and 3 represent shoes. i don't know how to take each quantity and send it in a format like that

have a look on my adapter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.cepheuen.elegantnumberbutton.view.ElegantNumberButton;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Currency;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

import app.gify.co.id.R;
import app.gify.co.id.activity.List_Kado;
import app.gify.co.id.modal.MadolCart;

public class AdapterCart extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<MadolCart> carts;
    MadolCart mm;
    View view;
    View viewku;
    Context context;
    int kuantitas;
    String totalname;
    int totalBerat, totalharga;
    TextView totalhargas, totalberats;

    public AdapterCart(ArrayList<MadolCart> carts, Context context, TextView totalhargas, TextView totalberats) {
        this.carts = carts;
        this.context = context;
        this.totalhargas = totalhargas;
        this.totalberats = totalberats;
    }

    public class MyCart extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView gambar, tambah, kurang;
        public TextView harga, nama, quantitas;
        public RelativeLayout background, foreground;
        public ElegantNumberButton quantity;

        public MyCart(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            gambar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.gambarcart);
            tambah = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tambahcart);
            kurang = itemView.findViewById(R.id.kurangcart);
            harga = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hargacart);
            nama = itemView.findViewById(R.id.namacart);
            quantitas = itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantitas);
            background = itemView.findViewById(R.id.background);
            foreground = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foreground);
            quantity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_cart, parent, false);
        viewku = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cart, parent, false);
        return new MyCart(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        kuantitas = carts.get(position).getJumlah();
        int hargaku = carts.get(position).getHarga() * kuantitas;
        for (int a = 0; a < carts.size(); a++){
            Log.d("cartsizeku", "onBindViewHolder: " + carts.size()+ " s " + carts.get(a).getNamacart() + " s " + carts.get(a).getHarga());
            String nama = carts.get(position).getNamacart();
            if (nama.equals(carts.get(a).getNamacart())){
                totalhargas.setText(String.valueOf(totalCart(carts, carts.get(a).getNamacart())));
                totalberats.setText(String.valueOf(beratCart(carts, carts.get(a).getNamacart())));
            }

        }

        Locale locale = new Locale("id", "ID");
        NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);

        ((MyCart)holder).harga.setText(format.format(Double.valueOf(hargaku)));
        ((MyCart)holder).nama.setText(carts.get(position).getNamacart());
        Glide.with(view).load(carts.get(position).getGambar()).into(((MyCart)holder).gambar);
        Intent intent = new Intent("message_subject_intent");
//        intent.putExtra("name", String.valueOf((totalCart(carts))));
        intent.putExtra("title", String.valueOf((getName(carts))));
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);


        ((MyCart) holder).tambah.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int count = Integer.parseInt(((MyCart) holder).quantitas.getText().toString());
                if (count<9){
                    count+=1;
                    ((MyCart)holder).quantitas.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                    int harga = carts.get(position).getHarga()*count;
                    ((MyCart)holder).harga.setText(String.valueOf(format.format(Double.valueOf(harga))));
                    String nama = carts.get(position).getNamacart();
                    totalhargas.setText(String.valueOf(totalCart(carts, nama)));
                    totalberats.setText(String.valueOf(beratCart(carts, nama)));
                }

//                ((MyCart)holder).quantitas.setText(String.valueOf(kuantitas));
                int total = hargaku * kuantitas;
                Intent intents = new Intent("message_subject_intent");
                intents.putExtra("name", String.valueOf((getName(carts))));
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intents);
            }
        });
        ((MyCart) holder).kurang.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int count = Integer.parseInt(((MyCart)holder).quantitas.getText().toString());
                if (count>1){
                    count-=1;
                    ((MyCart)holder).quantitas.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                    int harga = carts.get(position).getHarga()*count;
                    ((MyCart)holder).harga.setText(String.valueOf(format.format(Double.valueOf(harga))));
                    String nama = carts.get(position).getNamacart();
                    totalhargas.setText(String.valueOf(kurangtotalcart(carts, nama)));
                    totalberats.setText(String.valueOf(kurangberatCart(carts, nama)));
                }


//                ((MyCart)holder).quantitas.setText(String.valueOf(kuantitas));
                int total = hargaku * kuantitas;
                Intent intents = new Intent("message_subject_intent");
                intents.putExtra("name", String.valueOf((getName(carts))));
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intents);


            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return carts.size();
    }

    public int totalCart(ArrayList<MadolCart> items, String name){

        for(int i = 0 ; i < items.size(); i++) {
            totalname = items.get(i).getNamacart();
            if (totalname.equals(name)){
                totalharga += items.get(i).getHarga();
            }
        }
        return totalharga;
    }
    public int kurangtotalcart(ArrayList<MadolCart> items, String name){

        for(int i = 0 ; i < items.size(); i++) {
            totalname = items.get(i).getNamacart();
            if (totalname.equals(name)){
                totalharga -= items.get(i).getHarga();
            }
        }
        return totalharga;
    }

    public int beratCart(ArrayList<MadolCart> items, String name){
        for(int i = 0 ; i < items.size(); i++) {
            totalname = items.get(i).getNamacart();
            if (totalname.equals(name)){
                totalBerat += items.get(i).getBerat();
            }
        }
        return totalBerat;
    }

    public int kurangberatCart(ArrayList<MadolCart> items, String name){
        for(int i = 0 ; i < items.size(); i++) {
            totalname = items.get(i).getNamacart();
            if (totalname.equals(name)){
                totalBerat -= items.get(i).getBerat();
            }
        }
        return totalBerat;
    }

    public String getName(List<MadolCart> name){

        String ku = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++){
            ku += name.get(i).getNamacart() + ", ";
        }

        return ku;
    }

    public void removeItem(int item){
        carts.remove(item);

        notifyItemRemoved(item);
    }

    public void restoreItem(MadolCart madolCart, int item){
        carts.add(item, madolCart);

        notifyItemInserted(item);
    }

    public void quantityPlus(MadolCart madolCart, int item){


    }

}
```

and this is my activity

```
package app.gify.co.id.activity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.SpannedString;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ItemTouchHelper;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.DrawableImageViewTarget;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Currency;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Random;

import app.gify.co.id.R;
import app.gify.co.id.adapter.AdapterCart;
import app.gify.co.id.modal.MadolCart;
//import app.gify.co.id.thirdparty.GMailSender;
//import app.gify.co.id.thirdparty.SenderAgent;
import app.gify.co.id.widgets.RecyclerTouchDelete;

import static app.gify.co.id.baseurl.UrlJson.DELETECART;
import static app.gify.co.id.baseurl.UrlJson.GETBARANG;
import static app.gify.co.id.baseurl.UrlJson.GETCART;

public class CartActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerTouchDelete.RecyclerTouchListener{

    Button Checkout, lanjutBelanja;
    ImageView backCart;
    TextView totalbelanjar, totalberat;
    AdapterCart adapterCart;
    ArrayList<MadolCart> madolCarts;
    String namacart, gambarcart, uidku;
    GridLayoutManager glm;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    MainActivity mainActivity;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    public int hargaku, beratku, kuantitas, lastNumber, idbarang, getHargaAwal;
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Spanned templateConvert;
    NumberFormat format;
    Locale id;
    Random random;
    String template, idberat, idharga;
    private Dialog dialog;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ImageView goku;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cart);
        lanjutBelanja = findViewById(R.id.lanjutBelanjaChart);
        lanjutBelanja.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), List_Kado.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        });

        getHargaAwal = getIntent().getIntExtra("harga", 0);

        Log.d("setHarga", getHargaAwal + "");

        dialog  = new Dialog(CartActivity.this);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.loading, null);
        goku = layout.findViewById(R.id.custom_loading_imageView);
        goku.animate().rotationBy(360).setDuration(3000).setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()).start();
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setContentView(layout);
        dialog.show();

        id = new Locale("id", "ID");

        format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(id);

        random = new Random();
        lastNumber = 0;

        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++){
            lastNumber+=(random.nextInt(10)*Math.pow(10, k));
        }

        backCart = findViewById(R.id.backCartNav);
        backCart.setOnClickListener(v -> finish());

        Checkout = findViewById(R.id.checkoutChart);
        totalbelanjar = findViewById(R.id.totalBelanjaChart);
        totalberat = findViewById(R.id.totalBeratChart);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvChart);

        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(CartActivity.this);
        uidku = preferences.getString("uid", "");
        madolCarts = new ArrayList<>();
        getCart();
        glm = new GridLayoutManager(CartActivity.this, 1);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(glm);

        Checkout.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(CartActivity.this, CheckoutActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("idharga", idharga);
            intent.putExtra("name", namacart);
            preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.remove("range");
            editor.remove("acara");
            editor.remove("buat");
            editor.apply();
            startActivity(intent);

        });

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(passValue, new IntentFilter("message_subject_intent"));

        ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback callback = new RecyclerTouchDelete(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT, this);
        new ItemTouchHelper(callback).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    public String LoadData(String inFile) {
        String tContents = "";

        try {
            InputStream stream = getAssets().open(inFile);

            int size = stream.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            stream.read(buffer);
            stream.close();
            tContents = new String(buffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Handle exceptions here
        }

        return tContents;

    }

    private String replaceNumberOfAmount(String original, int replace){
        return original.substring(0, original.length() - 3) + replace;
    }

//    private void senderEmail(){
//        SenderAgent senderAgent = new SenderAgent("gify.firebase@gmail.com", "Confirmation Transaction Gify", templateConvert, CartActivity.this);
//        senderAgent.execute();
//    }

    private void getCart(){
        JsonObjectRequest objectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, GETCART, null, response -> {
            try {
                JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("YukNgaji");
                for (int a = 0; a < array.length(); a++){
                    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(a);
                    String id_tetap = object.getString("id_tetap");
                    if (id_tetap.equalsIgnoreCase(uidku)){
                        kuantitas = object.getInt("jumlah");
                        idbarang = object.getInt("id_barang");
                        idharga = object.getString("harga");
                        idberat = object.getString("berat");
                        getBerat(idbarang);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
                dialog.dismiss();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }, error -> {
            Log.d("getcart", "getCart: " + error.getMessage());
        });
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(CartActivity.this);
        queue.add(objectRequest);
    }

    public BroadcastReceiver passValue = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            namacart = intent.getStringExtra("name");
            Log.d("hargalast", namacart + "");
            namacart = intent.getStringExtra("title");
            template = "<h2> Gify Transaction </h2> " +
                    "<h3> Kamu baru saja melakukan pesanan dengan detail sebagai berikut </h3>"
                    + "<p><b> Nama barang: </p></b>"
                    + "<p><b> Harga barang" + format.format(Double.valueOf(replaceNumberOfAmount(idharga, lastNumber))) + ". Silahkan transfer dengan tiga digit terakhir yaitu :" + lastNumber + "</p></b>"
                    + "<p><b> Jika sudah melakukan pembayaran, silahkan konfirmasi disini </p></b>"
                    + "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=082325328732&text=Confirmation%20Text"
                    + "<h2>Salam, Gify Team</h2>";
            Log.d("hargalast", idharga + lastNumber);
            templateConvert = Html.fromHtml(template);
        }
    };

    private void getBerat(int idbarang){
        JsonObjectRequest objectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, GETBARANG, null, response -> {
            try {
                JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("YukNgaji");
                for (int a = 0; a < array.length(); a++){
                    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(a);
                    int id_barang = object.getInt("id");
                    if (idbarang==id_barang){
                        String gambar = object.getString("photo");
                        int harga = object.getInt("harga");
                        String namacart = object.getString("nama");
                        int berat = object.getInt("berat");
                        MadolCart madolCart = new MadolCart(gambar, harga, namacart, idbarang, kuantitas, berat);
                        madolCarts.add(madolCart);
                        adapterCart = new AdapterCart(madolCarts, CartActivity.this, totalbelanjar, totalberat);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterCart);
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }, error -> {
            Log.d("jsoner", "getBerat: " + error.getMessage());
        });
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(CartActivity.this);
        queue.add(objectRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwipe(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int dir, int pos) {
        if (viewHolder instanceof AdapterCart.MyCart){
            String name = madolCarts.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getNamacart();

            MadolCart madolCart = madolCarts.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            int deleteIndex =  viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();

            Log.d("taptap", "onSwipe: " + madolCarts.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getNamacart());

            GETBARANG(madolCarts.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getNamacart());

            adapterCart.removeItem(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    private void deletecart(String id_barang){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, DELETECART+"?idtetap="+uidku+"&idbarang="+id_barang, response -> {
            try {
                if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("bisa")){
                    Toast.makeText(CartActivity.this, "Barang telah di hapus", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("bisabarangcart", "GETBARANG: " );
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("ekscartactivity", "deletecart: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }, error -> {
            Log.d("ernocartdel", "deletecart: " + error.getMessage());
        });
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(CartActivity.this);
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void GETBARANG(String namas){
        JsonObjectRequest objectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, GETBARANG,null, response -> {
            try {
                JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("YukNgaji");
                for (int a = 0; a < array.length(); a++){
                    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(a);
                    String nama = object.getString("nama");
                    if (nama.equalsIgnoreCase(namas)){
                        Log.d("namabarang", "GETBARANG: " + nama + " s " + namas);
                        String id = object.getString("id");
                        deletecart(id);
                    }
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("barangexce", "GETBARANG: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }, error -> {
            Log.d("errorgetbrng", "GETBARANG: " + error.getMessage());
        });
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(CartActivity.this);
        queue.add(objectRequest);
    }

}
```

to make sum of total prices i used this code

```
public int totalCart(ArrayList<MadolCart> items, String name){

    for(int i = 0 ; i < items.size(); i++) {
        totalname = items.get(i).getNamacart();
        if (totalname.equals(name)){
            totalharga += items.get(i).getHarga();
        }
    }
    return totalharga;
}
```

i put summing code in a method, and call the method on if button + is clicked

if button - is clicked it will call this method

```
public int kurangtotalcart(ArrayList<MadolCart> items, String name){

    for(int i = 0 ; i < items.size(); i++) {
        totalname = items.get(i).getNamacart();
        if (totalname.equals(name)){
            totalharga -= items.get(i).getHarga();
        }
    }
    return totalharga;
}
```

and now idk how to get seperated quanitity for each position / item in recycler view then send it to activity as format ( 1, 2, 3) (,) mean a seperator for each item
**How to get value seperated quantity from recycler view item position?**

**SOLVED**

```
public String getSeperatedquantity(List<MadolCart> quantity){

    String kus = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < quantity.size(); i++){
        kus += quantity.get(i).getQuantity() + ", ";
    }

    return kus;
}
```

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by adding this:

```
public String getSeperatedquantity(List<MadolCart> quantity){

        String kus = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < quantity.size(); i++){
            kus += quantity.get(i).getQuantity() + ", ";
        }

        return kus;
    }
```